# Change :root variable via Javascript or JQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My goal is to use the dynamically calculated distance of li.ecs-event:nth-child(1) to the top for the top property in the btn-1 class via :root. The getposition function should work, not quite sure where I went off the path on the rest.

CSS:

```
:root {
  --mouse-x: 0vw;
  --mouse-y: 0vh;
}

.btn-1 {
  top: var(--mouse-y);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.querySelector('li.ecs-event:nth-child(1)');
    
var r = document.querySelector(':root');

function getPosition(element) {

    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }

    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };

}

function myFunction_set() {
    r.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', xPosition + "vw");
    r.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', yPosition + "vh");
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what the expected output is, and what your error is.

Comment: If a child gets added to the list "li.ecs-event:nth-child(1)" is the first child of, "li.ecs-event:nth-child(1)"'s distance to the top decreases. In this case, the value of "top: var(--mouse-y)" should change accordingly. In other words, I am trying to fetch the changes of the getPosition() function output and have the top property of the btn-1 class change accordently. To my understand, this can be done by ways of :root. I am not getting any errors, the problem is just that the top property value doesn't change